# Implement a version of the fetch API call using the native JS APIs(i.e. XMLHttpRequest())

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to implement my own version of fetch using XMLHttpRequest. I've got most of it done but stomped on why it's not working properly.

I've my jsbin link you can try out:
http://jsbin.com/jakahom/107/edit?html,js,console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need add **url**

```
request.open(options.method,url);
```

**complete**

```
fetch = {};
fetch.fetch = function(url, options) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if(typeof options.method === undefined) {
      options.method = 'GET'
    }

    request.open(options.method,url)

    if(typeof options.headers !== undefined) {
      options.headers.forEach(function(header) {
        request.setRequestHeader(header.name, header.value)
      });
    }

    request.onload = function() {
      if(this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
        resolve(request.response);
      }else {
        reject({
          status: this.status,
          statusText: this.statusText
        });
      }
    };

    request.onerror = function() {
      reject({
        status: this.status,
        statusText: this.statusText
      });
    };
    request.send();
  });
}

//Test
var options = {
  method : "GET",
  headers: [
    {name: "From", value: "test@test.com"}
  ]
};

fetch.fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos', options).then(function(data) {
  var json = JSON.parse(data);
  console.log(json);

}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

want to help you.